# debugging: show all the values

Tags: r

I'm trying to debug the `cosmo` R package because I'm trying to find out where all the motifs are.
I display some of them printing the "motif" variable but I don't know how to show all of the found motifs in one run.

http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.10/bioc/html/cosmo.html

I think that they must be in line 366 in "sites" variable in cosmo.R:

```
for (i in 1:com$selNumSites){
      site <- seqMat[com$alignStarts[i]:(com$alignStarts[i]+com$selWidth-1),
                     com$alignSeqs[i]]
      sites <- c(sites, toString(site))
```

But when I try to debug it I need first to load the cosmo library, then read the data and then run cosmo:

```
library(cosmo)
seqal <- system.file("Exfiles/short702k.FASTA", package="cosmo")
res <- cosmo(seqs=seqal, constraints="None", minW=10, maxW=10, models="TCM" )
```

For debugging line 366 I think I should:

```
library(cosmo)
seqal <- system.file("Exfiles/short702k.FASTA", package="cosmo")
setBreakpoint("cosmo.R",366)
res <- cosmo(seqs=seqal, constraints="None", minW=10, maxW=10, models="TCM" )
```

But I don't get any value of any variable..

And it doesn't seem to be the easiest way to get the sites variable values..

Answer (score 1):

`setBreakpoint` is intended for debugging R code loaded with the `source` function. If mysource.R is some source file with a function `f` defined at line 2, then

```
source('mysource.R')
setBreakpoint('mysource.R', 2)
```

would set a breakpoint at the beginning of the function `f` defined at line 2. Calling `library(cosmo)` isn't the same as calling `source('cosmo.R')`, so your call to `setBreakpoint` probably gave you the message 'No source refs found'.

If you want to set a breakpoint at the specific line in the `cosmo` function defined in `cosmo.R`, use

```
library(cosmo)
trace(cosmo, at=line.no)
```

where `line.no` is the line number relative to the start of the definition of `cosmo`. `untrace` turns off the breakpoint.